# Calculating mean values yearly in a dataframe with a new value daily

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, mean

I have this dataframe, which contains average temps for all the summer days:

```
DATE    TAVG
0   1955-06-01  NaN
1   1955-06-02  NaN
2   1955-06-03  NaN
3   1955-06-04  NaN
4   1955-06-05  NaN
... ... ...
5805    2020-08-27  2.067854
5806    2020-08-28  3.267854
5807    2020-08-29  3.067854
5808    2020-08-30  1.567854
5809    2020-08-31  4.167854
```

And I want to calculate the mean value yearly, so I can plot it, how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, can you try this ?

```
df['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df.groupby(df['DATE'].dt.year)['TAVG'].mean()
```